# Evaluate coefficients $A_{m,r}, \ 0\leq r\leq m$ in the identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let be a power function $f_{r,n}(s)$ defined as follows
\begin{equation}\label{f1}
f_{r,n}(s)=
\begin{cases}
s^r, \ &0\leq s\leq n,\\
0,  \ &\mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The following indentity involving convolution of $f_{r,n}(s)$ holds

$$(n+1)^{2m+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}(f_{r,n}*f_{r,n})[n]$$

Since the $f_{r,n}(s)$ defined only on the interval $[0,n]$ of real set, we can conclude the following identity
\begin{equation}\label{der1}
(f_{r,n}*f_{r,n})[n]\equiv\sum_{m=0}^{n}m^r(n-m)^r
\end{equation}
Definition of $A_{m,j}$ coefficients says that
\begin{equation}
(n+1)^{2m+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}(f_{r,n}*f_{r,n})[n]\equiv\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^r(n-k)^r
\end{equation}
Expanding $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^r(n-k)^r$ and applying Faulhaber's formula, we get
\begin{equation}\label{proof2}
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^r(n-k)^r
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^r \sum_{j} (-1)^j\binom{r}{j} n^{r-j}k^{j}=\sum_{j} (-1)^j\binom{r}{j} n^{r-j}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{r+j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j} \binom{r}{j} n^{r-j}\frac{(-1)^j}{r+j+1}\left[\sum_{s}\binom{r+j+1}{s}B_{s}n^{r+j+1-s}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j,s}\binom{r}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{r+j+1}\binom{r+j+1}{s}B_{s}n^{2r+1-s},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $B_s$ are Bernoulli numbers.
Now, we notice that
\begin{equation}\label{proof3}
\sum_{j} \binom{r}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{r+j+1}\binom{r+j+1}{s}
=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(2r+1)\binom{2r}r}, & \text{if } s=0;\\
\frac{(-1)^r}{s}\binom{r}{2r-s+1}, & \text{if } s>0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In particular, the last sum is zero for $0<s\leq r$. Therefore, expression (2.3) takes the form
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^r(n-k)^r=\frac{1}{(2r+1)\binom{2r}r}n^{2r+1}+\sum_{s>0}\frac{(-1)^s}{s}\binom{r}{2r-s+1}B_{s}n^{2r+1-s}
\end{equation}
Using the definition of $A_{m,j}$, we obtain the following identity for polynomials in $n$
\begin{equation}
(\star)\sum_{r}\frac{1}{(2r+1)\binom{2r}r}n^{2r+1}A_{m,r}+\sum_{r,s>0}\frac{(-1)^s}{s}\binom{r}{2r-s+1}B_{s}n^{2r+1-s}A_{m,r}\equiv (n+1)^{2m+1}
\end{equation}

**Question:** How to evaluate the coefficients $A_{m,r}$ from last step $(\star)$ ?

This problem is closely related to the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297900/, but still solution is unclear for me